# Can't reset password for postgresql db

Tags: postgresql, psql

This question has probably already been answered here somewhere but after three days I haven't been able to find a solution and I think I have checked all of stackoverflow.

My problem is that I have forgotten the password (or at least can't login) to my postgresql database (v11).

I have in cmd (using windows 7) inputted

```
psql -h localhost -U 'my_user_name'
```

and get back "write in password" and after doing so I get

> psql FATAL: password authentication for user 'my_user_name'

Therefore I went into the pg_hba.conf file and changed the row

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

to

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

but when running psql -h localhost -U 'my_user_name'

I thereafter get

> "psql FATAL: user 'my_user_name' doesn't exist"

How can I sort this out? I just want to reset the password so that I can login to the database again.

Comment: Neither of those two errors can be fixed by editing pg_hba.conf - that file does not control the user accounts nor their passwords

Answer (score 0):

The postgres superuser likely still exists.  Try running `psql -h localhost -U postgres`

Then, you can alter your original user:

`ALTER USER my_user_name PASSWORD 'password';`

Comment: hi, the problem is that I have two postgresql databases and if I login to the "postgres" one as you suggest I get into version 10 but I want to login in to version 11. The reason for this is that all my data is on version 10 but I can't push my data to my heroku app since the app is on version 11.4 db(I think). Thereby I am trying to login to the version 11 db, push the data from v10 db to v11 db (locally) and then push data from v11 (locally) to my postgresql db at heroku.

Comment: Firstly, you can't have two clusters running on the same port.  It's possible you have multiple databases in your cluster, but you could specify a different one.  It sounds like it may be: `psql -h localhost -U postgres -d my_user_name` but it may be something else.

Comment: ok, that may be a problem then. I tried running the command you put but it gave "psql fatal database my_user_name doesnt exist".

but what is the best way to go forward?:
- separate databases to different ports
- take out data from v10 db to csv file and then erase that database and load csv file to v11 db?, 
 -- but will that fix the problem that I have now? (ie not being able to login to v11)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to trust all by the IP domain.
You need to change only by Unix socket domain connection

`local   all   all   trust`

Restart the PostgreSQL server
And to get logged in just you need the Username

`psql -U postgres`

Then just reset your password

`\password postgres`

Exit and revert change to config and restart for last time. you have access to your account with the new password.